# a Reactify Error :Unexpected identifier

Tags: reactjs

```js
var React = require('react');
var EventListItem = require('./EventListItem.js');

var EventList = React.createClass({
 var events = this.props.events;
 if (!Array.isArray(events)) throw new Error ('it must be Array');
 var eventsComps = events.map(function(eve){
  return (<EventListItem key={eve.key}
  title={eve.title}
  description={eve.description}
  voteCount={eve.voteCount} />)
 });

 render:function(){
  return(
   <div id="events" className="">
    
    {eventsComps}
    
   </div>
  );
 }
});

module.exports = EventList;
```

Line 5: Unexpected identifier
I search the problem and checked my ","or ";"but I don't find the problem,what's  wrong with it?

Comment: You cannot put arbitrary statements (e.g.  `var events = this.props.events;`) inside an object literal (`{...}`). It looks like all that code should be inside the `render` function. You can learn more about JavaScript basics here: http://eloquentjavascript.net .

Comment: That's an object literal, not a block. You can't have statements like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write any random statements inside an `object literal`. All you code need to be inside you render function or you must define a different function and write this code inside it.

```
var React = require('react');
var EventListItem = require('./EventListItem.js');

var EventList = React.createClass({

    render:function(){
            var {events} = this.props;
        if (!Array.isArray(events)) throw new Error ('it must be Array');
           var eventsComps = events.map(function(eve){
           return (<EventListItem key={eve.key}
           title={eve.title}
           description={eve.description}
           voteCount={eve.voteCount} />)
        });
        return(
            <div id="events" className="">

                {eventsComps}

            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = EventList;
```